# Knockout JS Calling a ViewModel function inside a foreach binding

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Let's consider a view model using knockout like that:

```
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "John Doe" }, { id: 2, name: ""}, { id: 3, name: "Peter Parker"}];

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(data)
};

viewModel.showName = function (name) {
    console.log(this);
    return name && name.length > 0;
};

viewModel.removePerson = function () {
    console.log(this); 
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

With this View:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><span data-bind="text: id"></span>
         <span data-bind="visible: $root.showName(name)">Yes! show the name</span>
         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removePerson">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/SmW35/8/

In this case, when someone clicks the "Remove" link, and KO calls the showName function,
the object "this" inside the function, it's an object with the current item, for example, if I click "remove" in the item 2, "this" is {id: 2, name: ""}
However, when KO is binding the "visible" and calls the showName function, the "this" object doesn't contains the current item, and you have to pass "name" to the function (or you could use the $data).

So, I have 2 questions:

- There's a way to call the showName function from the View, without passing the name or $data (similar behaviour than with the Remove link)
- If not, there's something wrong do it that way? I have an interesting discussion with a workmate that thinks that is not right do it that way because you are sending data from the View ($root.showName(name)), and then this is not a "pure" MVVM pattern. He's proposing create a custom KO binding to achieve the functionality. In my opinion is killing flies with a tank, but I'm very curious to know if there's a different way or you also think I'm not doing a pure MVVM pattern with my code.

Comment: out of interest why would you hide the name span but leave the button visible. If you want to hide both then there is a different solution that what Luis describes below

Comment: @RobertSlaney the remove button is there only for helping to understand what I was asking. THere' no remove button in my project, and the showName is for other purposes (but exactly the same simplicity). thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a sense your colleague has a point. I wouldn't personally create a custom binding to handle this though (on a continued subjective note, custom bindings are more intended if there's a special way of communication between a view and view model; see [this post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) for a great explanation of when to use them).

On a side note, if we *do* explore the option of a custom binding, I guess you can do something like a `textIfNotEmpty` binding handler that combines `text` and `visible` in one. On the other hand, if the `showName` functionality stays as simple as it is you could also go for:

```html
<span data-bind="visible: !!name, text: name"></span>
```

In any case, I'd prefer the following...

The underlying problem is IMO that the View Model is violating the Single Responsibility principle: the `showName` functionality should be the responsibility of a View Model representing an item.

```
var Item = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;

    self.name = ko.observable(data.name); 
    // or plain "self.name = data.name;" if you don't need 2way binding

    self.showName = ko.computed(function() { 
         return self.name() && self.name().length > 0;
    });
}
```

Now you can easily bind like this:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><span data-bind="text: id"></span>
         <span data-bind="visible: showName">Yes! show the name</span>
         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removePerson">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which also allows you to rewrite the `removePerson` to this:

```
viewModel.removePerson = function (person) {
    console.log(person); 
};
```

This does require you to do a wee bit of extra work in constructing the observable array, but it's worth it as it clearly seperates all the concerns. It could be done along these lines:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(data.map(function(item) { return new Item(item); }))
};
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbD8J/) for a demo of the above.

Comment: thanks a lot. 2 comments: 1) I guess there's a mistake in the View, and the "visible: showName(name)" should be "visible: showName()". 2) I don't see that my View has any logic, the logic is in the showName function. The view is only sending the value of Name. Anyway, I understand your example and I can agree that is more MVVM pure, but also more work. Not sure if it worth. thanks again!

Comment: Ah yeah, guess you're right on both counts. In any case, SO isn't very good for discussing the subjective bits, so please view my answer merely as an alternative way of achieving what you want. It's a case-by-case (subjective) decision which approach to finally go with. Good luck!

Comment: PS. If you find any bugs or flaws in my code feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, I'm the colleague and I agree with you to have an Item "class" and use that as a DTO. But the problem is the team that I working with. They have low js skills and just think to map the data array from the json that you get to DTOs make my life very complicated.

Anyway usually I use DTOs to resolve issue like that and the custom binding was a work around to keep the code clean and fix the issue asap.

In this link there is another example of DTO that I used 2 years ago: https://github.com/Salvodif/MyPlayboxArea/blob/master/MVC/MvcApplication1/Scripts/SDF.DTO.js